# Reactive Cocoa: subscribe only to new values

Tags: ios, cocoa, reactive-cocoa

I'm new to Reactive Cocoa. What I'm trying to achieve is get notified every time property value changes. However, I don't want to get notified when property is set to the same value.
Here's some code:

```
self.testProperty = 0;
[[RACObserve(self, self.testProperty) skip:1] subscribeNext:^(id x) {
    NSLog(@"Did Change: %@", x);
}];

self.testProperty = 1;
self.testProperty = 1;
self.testProperty = 1;
self.testProperty = 1;
self.testProperty = 1;
```

And this is what I get on console's output

```
> Did Change: 1
> Did Change: 1
> Did Change: 1
> Did Change: 1
> Did Change: 1
```

I expected that "Did change" would be printed only once, not five. Is there any way to subscribe only to new values?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a method for that, [distinctUntilChanged](http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/ReactiveCocoa/2.5/Classes/RACStream.html#//api/name/distinctUntilChanged):

```
[[[RACObserve(self, self.testProperty) 
  skip:1]
  distinctUntilChanged]
  subscribeNext:^(id x) {
    NSLog(@"Did Change: %@", x);
}];
```